# How to .call() on the unnamed function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Let's suppose I have button `#click`,

And suppose I bind the on click event as follows:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
   alert('own you'+'whatever'+$(this).attr('href'));
});
```

But I want `this` to refer to some other element, let's say `#ahref`.

If it was a named function I would simply refer it by name:

```
foo.call('#ahref');
```

How could I use `.call()` though, if the function is called inline and does not have a name?

Comment: Anonymous has problems with anonymous functions :)

Comment: If you know how to do it with a named function, why don't you just use one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function to change a context:

```
$('#click').click($.proxy(function() {
    alert('own you'+'whatever'+$(this).attr('href'));
}, $('#ahref')));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well, and as long as Jquery is concerned it must be a way to go - for a build in solution.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force jQuery to invoke the function with a `this` value of anything other than what jQuery wants it to be.  That said, you could pass jQuery a function that calls your function with your predetermined `this` by using `.bind()`:

```
$('#click').click(function() {
  // whatever
}.bind(someObject));
```

The `.bind()` method on the Function prototype returns a function that calls the original function (your anonymous event handler) with the object you pass as `this`.  It's in newer browsers, and there's a [shim at the Mozilla documentation site.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

*edit* — alternatively see @dfsq's answer involving the similar `$.proxy()` function from jQuery itself.

Comment: Hmm, both solution worked! Thanks for the answer. But I simply can't get it, what actually makes this `.bind()` method work?

Comment: @Anonymous I forgot to put a link to the shim at MDN - I'll add that. It just returns a function that uses `.call` - note that because `.bind()` is called as a method of the function object, inside `.bind()` `this` will be a reference to the function itself. In other words, when you call `.bind()` like that it makes the function effectively not anonymous, because `this` refers to it.

Comment: Hehe, very crooked! Thanks for sharing, I learned a lot here :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but what's stopping you from accessing that other element directly?

```
$('#click').click(function(){
   alert('own you'+'whatever' + $('#ahref').attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're after, but you can bind the context like this:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
   alert('own you'+'whatever'+this.attr('href'));
}.bind($('#ahref')));
```